# Stealthy way to watch browser behavior Windows (preferably without paying for software)?

Tags: windows, screenshot

I need to monitor one employee which keeps removing his Firefox history or goes into private mode. What are the ways I can make Windows save its screen contents periodically or in any other ways lets me find out which websites were being watched?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Okay, I'll rewrite the question in a sec.

Comment: Log them at your router. If it doesn't support it, get a better router. ;)

Comment: Replacing the router is not an option.

Comment: Don't allow Firefox to be used and change to group policy to prevent any change to IE settings

Comment: I could as well painfully kill the employee. No, replacing FF with IE is not really an option.

Comment: Just tell the employee that using private mode or purging history is a violation of company policy and will lead to written warnings and termination.  No need to be all passive-agressive when you can just be up-front and actually communicate.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of firefox is an option, I doubt the employee owns this equipment, the company does.

Comment: @d33tah Give me a break of course it's an option considering its a free solution.  Firefox can also be domained managed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the best way to monitor and record the URLs called by device to establish or monitor browsing history?](http://superuser.com/questions/430804/what-is-the-best-way-to-monitor-and-record-the-urls-called-by-device-to-establis)

Comment: I removed the caveat regarding free, and mention of software you'd like alternatives to as a possible solution. If you are going to define pricing and ask for alternative software, then you are defining that you are looking for product recommendations, which (again) are off topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to track websites that have been visited?](http://superuser.com/questions/52181/how-to-track-websites-that-have-been-visited)

Comment: Firefox group policy solution http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxadm/ there is also a Firefox extension that exists.

Answer (score 1):

DopeGhoti has a good point, and before you install snooping software on your own computer to monitor someone's usage without their permission, check your state's laws regarding this. I'm not a lawyer, but it would not be a good day if you were to find yourself at the end of a lawsuit while attempting to protect your business.

If a software based solution is needed, you might be better off setting up a proxy server, and have the user(s) go through there. All locations he visits would be logged, which you could then use that along with your workplace policy regarding usage of computer equipment. Don't want to fork over the money for an MS solution? Try Linux! IPCop, Smoothwall Express and other distros have been especially created for small offices which require enterprise-level security. When I use to consult, I would configure a x86 box with two NICs, IPCop and some addons such as a proxy server, updates repository (one machine downloads updates from Microsoft, the rest of the computers in your network get a locally cached copy) etc.

Comment: Monitoring software isn't even beinging used by the sounds of it.  I would be shocked if any browsing logged.

Comment: I'm no lawyer either, but if the guy's doing something he shouldn't be on company time on a company computer, the law is not on his side.

Comment: Depends on the state. Some states protect the employee's privacy, which includes browsing. That's why most companies have well defined policies so that when something happens, there's a legal recourse. Just saying. If it were me, I would try to CMA. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you code something in AutoIt. It is not that hard. There already may be an example program doing just this. Search here
http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/forum/9-example-scripts/

example function
http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ScreenCapture_Capture.htm